# Calculate the line integral$ \int_\gamma{\frac{d\xi}{\xi^4+1}}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Calculate
$$ \int_\gamma{\frac{d\xi}{\xi^4+1}}$$

$y(t)$ is the circumfernce $x^2+y^2=2x$

I tried this for the parametrization.
$$x^2+y^2=2x$$
$$x^2-2x+y^2=0$$
$$x^2-2x+1+y^2=1$$
$$(x-1)^2+y^2=1$$
$$z_0=1, R=1$$

$$\gamma(t)=1+e^{it}, \,\,\,0\leq t\leq 2\pi$$

I did partial fractions, but i get confused in this part:
$$\frac{1}{\xi^4+1}=\frac{1}{2i(\xi^2+i)}+\frac{1}{2i(\xi^2-i)}$$

$$ \int_\gamma{\frac{d\xi}{\xi^4+1}}=\frac{1}{2i}\int{-\frac{1}{\xi^2+i}+\frac{1}{\xi^2-i}}$$

How do I apply the cauchy formula?
$$f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma{\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz}$$

Comment: General formula : $\int_{[0,2\pi]} f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t)\mathrm{d}t$ with $f= ?$

Comment: Your approach is correct, and it leads to the computation of the integral
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ie^{it}}{(1+e^{it})^4+1}~dt,$$
which is a doable but difficult computation. It is much easier to use the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) here (if you are familiar with it).

Comment: Is it the same as the residue theorem of a pole of order n? The pole order would be 4? :c

Comment: @qw.15125 There are 4 simple poles (order 1), and only 2 of those poles are contained in the interior of $\gamma$.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to use the residue theorem. Note that the roots of $z^4+1$ are $e^{\pi i k/4}$ for $k=1,3,5,7$. The only roots contained in the interior of your curve are $e^{\pi i/4}$ and $e^{7\pi i/4}$. So $$ \int_\gamma{\frac{d\xi}{\xi^4+1}}=2\pi i(Res(f,e^{\pi i/4})+Res(f,e^{7\pi i/4}))=\frac{2\pi i}{4}(e^{-\pi i/4}+e^{-7\pi i/4})=\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi i}{2}$$

Comment: Is f = $z^4+1$?